# How collect metadata/os info about ec2 instance to file?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata

I want to create a script that gathers information about the ec2 instance ( id, ip, os, users mb other if needed ), but i need help with getting info about running system - i think it easy to get OS info from /etc/os-release ? And the second question about yaml - is it possible parse output to data.txt as yaml ?
 Please help me add OS info to data.txt :)

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/"

which curl > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
 get_cmd="curl -s"
else
  get_cmd="wget -q -O -"  
fi


get () {
$get_cmd $URL/$1
}

data_items=(instance-id
        local-ipv4
        public-ipv4
        )


yaml=""

for meta_thing in ${data_items[*]}; do
   data=$(get $meta_thing)
   entry=$(printf "%-30s%s" "$meta_thing:" "$data\n")
yaml="$yaml$entry"
done

echo -e "$yaml" > data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe add

```
lsb_release -a >> data.txt
uname -a >> data.txt
```

To the end of the script